# Notifications in elevator simulator in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, wait, notify

I am trying to implement an elevator simulator with Person and Elevator threads that share data in an ElevatorController class.  My general implementation is that I have each Person store a controller variable, and from there, they request a ride in the elevator(current floor to some other floor).  The controller keeps track of the requests, and the Elevator threads ask the controller for a new assignment(which floors to stop at and direction), which it generates based on the requests.  The part I am having trouble with is the notification that the doors are open on a floor.  I have tried putting a boolean array in the ElevatorController and have the Person threads call wait() (within a synchronized block on controller.areDoorsOpen) and then calling notifyAll on the areDoorsOpen array from the controller but I keep getting IllegalMonitorStateExceptions.  My idea was that when the Person threads are notified (controller does so when it changes an entry in the areDoorsOpen array), they check the boolean array to see if the door is open on their floor (or if they are in the elevator, on their destination floor) and enter (or exit) the elevator or continue waiting. My question is why am I getting this exception on the wait() call in the person runnable.

Edit: The relevant code is
In the person Runnable,

```
private void waitForElevator() {
        synchronized (controller.areDoorsOpenOn) {
        System.out.printf("Person %d is waiting on floor %d to go to floor %d.\n", ID, currentFloor, destinationFloor);
        while(!controller.areDoorsOpenOn[currentFloor]) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller class,

```
public boolean[] areDoorsOpenOn = new boolean[numberOfFloors];

public void notifyOpenDoors(int floor) {
    synchronized (areDoorsOpenOn) {
        areDoorsOpenOn[floor] = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

public void notifyClosedDoors(int floor) {
    synchronized (areDoorsOpenOn) {
        areDoorsOpenOn[floor] = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

The Elevator threads call notifyOpenDoors if they are on a floor that is in their assignment (stored as an array of integers) and then sleep for 3 seconds and call notifyClosedDoors
Thank you in advance for your help and let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ok. and what have you done till now ? show us some codes

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to what is found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) on Guarded Blocks, but my case is across multiple threads and using an array of booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace from the IllegalMonitorStateExceptions will tell you where that's coming from - an important clue.

I believe you need to rethink which objects you are calling wait() and notifyAll() on.  For example, you may want to always use areDoorsOpenOn.notifyAll() and areDoorsOpenOn.wait().  Currently, you're calling wait on the Runnable, and notifyAll on the Controllers.

Comment: It is being thrown on the wait() call in waitForElevator() in the Person class.  I was under the impression that since those calls are inside of the synchronized(areDoorsOpenOn) block that the wait and notifyAll calls would be on that object.  Is that not correct?

Comment: I guess not as this has fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help!